# Why is this code not reversing the words in a sentence?

Tags: c++, string

So I want to take the words in a sentence and flip the word, and only the word around. For example:

```
Hello there
```

would be changed to:

```
olleH ereht
```

So I tried doing so with the following code:

```
#include <iostream> //Include the necessary header files.
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::string sentence("Hello this is a sentence"); //This is the sentence I want to convert.
    char *tokens = strtok(strdup(sentence.c_str()), " "); //Tokenize the sentence.

    std::string tempToken; //Will use this to store the tokens in reverse.
    std::vector< std::string > strings; //This will keep all contents of the converted sentence.

    for (int i = (int)sentence.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) { //Go through the sentence backwards.

        if (tokens[i] == NULL) { //If tokens[i] == NULL then that was a complete token.

            strings.push_back(tempToken); //Push back the reversed token.
            tempToken.clear(); //Clear the reversed token so it can be used again to store another reveresed token.

        }
        else { //Still in the middle of a token

            tempToken.append(&tokens[i]); //Since I am iterating backwards this should store the token backwards...

        }
    }
    for (std::vector<std::string>::reverse_iterator it = strings.rbegin(); it != strings.rend(); ++it) { //Because I used strings.push_back(tempToken) I need to go through the vector backwards to maintain the word placement.

        std::cout << *it; //Print the words backwards.

    }
}
```

Basically, I take a sentence. Then I tokenize it. Loop through the string backwards and store the characters in a string until I reach the end of the token. When I reach the end of the token, I take the characters I just stored from looping backwards and put it into a vector. Then after I have done this with all the tokens I print out the contents of the vector.

When I run this program the sentence:

```
Hello this is a sentence
```

Gets converted to:

```
ecenceencetencentenceentencesentence sentencea sentence a sentences a sentenceis a sentence is a sentences is a sentenceis is a sentencehis is a sentencethis is a sentence
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Eewww, what's all this dirty C doing in the purported C++ program? Why not write a C++ solution? `strdup` isn't even in C, and this is memory leak central!

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `strtok` or `strdup` (plus you're forgetting to `free(tokens)`) when you have `string` available. It would be much easier to do this with `stringstream`.

Comment: Step through it in a debugger and see how the expected results differ from reality at each step.  I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: `delete tokens`?  I think not!!  It's allocated by strdup, so malloc, hence should be released using `free`,  not `delete`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck you're right. I hate the "C/C++" language. Love C++, hate C/C++.

Comment: I see a lot of C bashing, just want to say that "clean" C (to contrast with @KerrekSB's description of "dirty" C) looks much better than this.

Comment: @asveikau it only becomes dirty when you try to mix it with C++. Oil and water are fine on their own, but they don't mix.

Comment: @SethCarnegie That's not true.  Eventually there's going to be some room for more C-style stuff.  How else do your nice container classes and fancy RAII templates get written?

Comment: @asveikau that's not what I'm talking about, he doesn't mean that you should never use `int` because `int` is in C. It's a method of doing things, using certain things when you can and not choosing to do things that other people have already done for you. I'm just trying to explain what Kerrek meant by "dirty C".

Comment: And I'm saying if @anon had put well-written C, I would object to the use of the term "dirty".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Best to forget everything, and write C++ instead:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

void reverse_words(std::string const & sentence)
{
    std::istringstream iss(sentence);
    std::string word;
    while (iss >> word)
    {
        std::cout << std::string(word.rbegin(), word.rend()) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This will compress multiple spaces. +1 though.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: I'm not sure if `strtok` wouldn't have done the same; and for that matter, it's not clear whether "tokenization" doesn't actually mean that you want to normalize delimiters... but yes, if you want to preserve interword space, you have to work a bit harder.

Comment: @KerrekSB Don't you think the professor would suspect something fishy is going on if he sees **this** code? :) :) :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: If any so-called "professor" suggested char pointers and `strdup` in a C++ class, it's time to change schools and get a real education!

Comment: @KerrekSB: Thanks for a more C++ oriented solution. I need to start thinking in terms of C++ more.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I don't have a professor, at least not at the moment and I've been just looking at problems I found online and have been trying to solve them, I don't know what the right way is. Which is why I end up doing them wrong :(.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Family Guy- SideCharacter "My son just got into DeVry!", Peter: "What did he have to do, walk through the front door?" *laughter*

Comment: @anon: good for you trying to learn something on your own! There is real value in knowing how to learn on your own and how to recognize solid sources of reference.

Answer (score 1):

The `strtok` function doesn't tokenize in one call. It returns the next token each time you call it. Read the documentation more closely.

Comment: Oh, now I feel stupid... thanks for pointing that out. Ok, I'll try fixing it based off your advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
void main(string s){
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
strings = s.split(" ").toList();
string backwards = "";
foreach(string str in strings){
   string stri = str;
   for(int i = 0; i< str.length(); i++){
    backwards += stri.substr(stri.length() - 1);
    stri = stri.substr(0,stri.length() -1);
   }
   backwards += " ";
}
cout << backwards;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a well know question with a simple trick (to do it in place):

1. Reverse the string
2. For each word

   - Reverse the word

Try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    //  Get the line
    std::string  line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    // Reverse the whole line.
    std::reverse(line.begin(), line.end());

    // Find the start of the first word
    std::string::size_type beg = line.find_first_not_of(" \t");

    while(beg != std::string::npos)
    {
        // Find the end of the word we have found
        std::string::size_type end = line.find_first_of(" \t",beg);
        end = (end == std::string::npos ? line.size() : end);

        // Reverse the word
        std::reverse(&line[beg],&line[end]);

        // See if we can find the next word
         beg = line.find_first_not_of(" \t", end);
    }

    // Print the result.
    std::cout << line << "\n";
}
```

Comment: He's not modifying the return of `c_str`, he's using `strdup` to make a copy

Comment: Also you _can_ do `tokens[i] == NULL` but it doesn't do what he thinks it does.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
string reverseString(string inputStr){
    inputStr += ' ';
    int len = inputStr.size();
    len--;
    int j;
    for(int i=0;i<=len;i++){
        for( j=i ;inputStr[i] != ' ';i++);

      int ii=i;
      while(j<=ii){
      char temp = inputStr[ii];
      inputStr[ii] = inputStr[j];
      inputStr[j] = temp;
      j++;
      ii--;
      }
    }
return inputStr;
}
```